# C++ "|=" assignment operator

Tags: c++, variable-assignment, operator-keyword

My question is, what is the "|=" for in C++? I get that they are bitwise operators but i dont understand what they do here:

```
gObj->Variable |= 0x1000000;
```

Also, what does the "&" operator mean in this case?

```
if ((gObj->Variable & 2) == 2)
{
    do stuff
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_operators.

Comment: They would be used like your example when you have different flags, all represented by one bit. The first sets a flag, the second checks a flag.

Comment: If you know they are bitwise operators why not simply look to one of the thousands of existing resources available to you (including this site)?

Comment: That second code sample is not valid C?

Comment: Missing a parenthesis is all, I think.

Answer (score 5):

These are [bitwise operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation).

`|` stands for an [OR operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction) and `&` stands for an [AND operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction).

```
x |= y
```

is equivalent to

```
x = x | y
```

It is very common to use these operations with hexadecimal values, since it is much easier and very much intuitive. For instance:

```
0x10 | 0x01 = 0x11
0x10 & 0x01 = 0x00
0x10 & 0x11 = 0x10
```

Answer (score 3):

I am no C++ expert, but I believe these are treated like += or *=.  That is, it will bitwise OR the bits of that variable with the hex number you mentioned.  Also, Variable & 2 is doing a bitwise AND with 10 (binary).

Answer (score 0):

It is bitwise or operator and above statement will set the first bit of the variable to 1.